# What's the most beautiful navigation experience you've seen in an app in the last year?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, layout, design-patterns

I've noticed that all apps are becoming the same. Top and bottom navigation bars, and everything where you expect it to be.

This isn't necessarily a bad thing, but has anyone seen anything thing that truely breaks the mold?

Summly and Any.do come to mind. Any others?

Comment: Hi, sorry but this type of question isn't really a good fit for a Q&A site as all answers would be equally valid so can't be specifically answered. As per our [FAQ] *"We prefer questions that elicit definitive answers or solutions rather than prolonged discussions. Remember, this a Q&A site, not a discussion board."* It's more of a question for our chat site than the main board

Comment: If that's what you think is best. I'm glad someone got an answer in there before it was shutdown. It really helped and is one of the reasons I come to this site :)  Although, all answers are not equally valid, because I asked for a nontraditional navigation examples and that's exactly what HeyCameron Delivered. An answer like "Instagram, Cheddar or Gmail" would be clearly wrong. But what do I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really enjoyed stumbling upon "Ness". A food, restaurant finder.
The Navigation uses large appetizing images to navigate through their application. 
http://www.likeness.com/

[image: Resturant page]

Comment: Well done. That's beautiful. If I could upvote you I would :)